# powerpivot 2013 mysql 64 bit

Tags: windows-8, odbc, mysql-connector, powerpivot, excel-2013

I'm trying to download data from a remote mySQl server into the powerpivot 2013 excell addin.
the configurations are as follow:
- OS: windows 8
- Excel 2013 64 bit
- connector: tried both ODBC connectors 3.51.30 (i have working configuration with excel 2010 32 bit with that connector) and 5.2.5 (using unicode)

server side
innodb_version  1.1.8
protocol_version    10
slave_type_conversions
version 5.5.28-1
version_comment (Debian)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  debian-linux-gnu

if i get the connection through excel directly it works just fine but using the powrpivot addin i get following errors
1. if i go through the option "select tables and view"
then "No tables were found in the data source. Check the connection information and login credentials".

1. if i go through the query option then if i query
   select * from table

using the 3.51 connector
"Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."
if i use the design button: when i execute the select statement i see the column names but all data will show "error"

using the 5.2 connector

ERROR [HY010] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.28-1]

though if i click the design button and execute the query i get the data in that window

half way solution
after reading
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maria/archive/2012/07/05/quot-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-quot-error-running-a-report-that-uses-a-connection-data-source-to-oracle-10.aspx
i decided to uninstall my office 2013 64bit and install the 32 bit version
using the the 3.51 connector (32bit) everythign went back to normal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue connecting to JIRA from excel 2013 64bit with the 3.51 connector. I have been able to work around it by specifying particular fields I want to retrieve, instead of all fields. e.g.:
select id,assignee from jiradb.jiraissue

BUT when I hit a particular field (DESCRIPTION) the error returned. So I went back to the 32 bit Excel 2013 to avoid the problem.